# video play in mac application using qtmovieview

Tags: macos

I've written code like this

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iOS app development " ofType:@"mp4"];

NSLog(@" path   %@",path);

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] ;
movie1 = [QTMovie movieWithURL:url error:nil];

[Movieview setMovie:movie1];

[[Movieview movie]play];
```

when i run application only audio is playing. if any one know the answer please help me

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
[[movie1 window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:self];
```

It should fix your problem